# Keyboard overlapping input on iOS with React Native Webview

Tags: react-native, keyboard, react-native-webview

I have an issue with my React Native app, the keyboard is overlapping an input inside a `WebView` on iOS only, using `react-native-webview` when the property `scrollEnabled` is `false` and wrapping the webview inside a `KeyboardAvoidingView` component.
The `KeyboardAvoidingView` component is doing his job by adding bottom-padding and the web page has a scrollview that allow the user to scroll when the screen shrinks, but the web page is not scrolling by itself to display the input when the keyboard is displaying.

The Android app has no issue, it is not using the `KeyboardAvoidingView` component and it has `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` inside the `AndroidManifest`.

The code looks like this :

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior={isIos ? 'padding' : null}
  enabled={isIos}
>
    <WebView
          androidLayerType={'hardware'}
          hideKeyboardAccessoryView={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          cacheEnabled={true}
          overScrollMode={'never'}
          scrollEnabled={false}
        />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Do you have any ideas how to solve this issue?